# How to use open closed principle for web page operations invocation in java?

Tags: java, design-principles

I have a web page where users can fill in and submit forms:

```
 <form id=email...
 send email ....
 <input type="hidden"id="method" value="sendemail"...
 />
  .............

 <form id=writeindatabase
 some data
      ............
 <input type="hidden"id="method"  value="writeindatabase"...
```

On the server side:

```
if (method.compareTo("sendemail")==0) {
 doSendEmail(....
}
else if (method.compareTo("writeindatabase")==0) {
  doWriteInDatabase(....

 ..............................
```

I don't like this architecture because it violates the [open close principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).
Is it possible to refactor this to fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just have both forms redirect to different URLs?

Comment: What you could do is change the `action` attribute in your form and let the Container dispatch to the correct Servlet or Controller (eg. if you're using Spring).

Comment: I use MVC. It is only 1 web page. For 1 web page create many servlets and controllers  - will be more repeatable code. Answer should be the same page with added result of operation. Now I have 1 web page, 1 controller 1 view model. If I will create many servlets and controllers for 1 web page it will be difficult to make it work toghether.

Comment: I think about reflection. But not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection in a structured, secure manner, or, similarly the Command Pattern.

- **Reflection:** make a `Map<String, Method>` that maps each acceptable method name to a Reflection `Method` object which you can `invoke` after looking it up.
- **Command Pattern:** use a `Map<String, Callable<?>>` in a manner similar to above. Instantiate the `Callable`s as anonymous inner classes that implement `call` by invoking the appropriate service method.